# Problem with mono runtime installation-failures

Tags: 18.04

Hello everyone I am really disappointed please help me to fix my Ubuntu 18.04

Setting up msbuild (1:16.0+xamarinxplat.2018.09.26.17.53-0xamarin3+ubuntu1804b1) ...
Setting up msbuild-sdkresolver (1:16.0+xamarinxplat.2018.09.26.17.53-0xamarin3+ubuntu1804b1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libnunit-core-interfaces2.6.3-cil
 libnunit-core2.6.3-cil
 libnunit-cil-dev
 libnunit-console-runner2.6.3-cil
 libnunit-util2.6.3-cil
 libmono-cil-dev
 mono-devel
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

I really don't like re-install os of Ubuntu

PLEASE TELL ME HOW DO I FIX?
sudo dpkg --configure -a = no success
sudo apt autoremove -fy = sometimes crazy
sudo apt install -f and it says I should install or remove.

and more I am broken on floor. PLEASE TELL ME HOW DO I FIX? But I have already searched like here [Link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/357798/unable-to-remove-cli-library-packages/488083#488083)

And I have not success :( I hate reinstall with Ubuntu. PLEASE TELL ME I don't like much work.